# Changing Time Zones in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm looking for some clarification. When I run the following code what actually happens in FullCalendar? Does it cause the event feed to be re-read?

```
<div id="timeZonePicker">
    Time Zones
    <select id="timezone-selector">
        <option value='' selected>none</option>
        <option value='local'>local</option>
        <option value='UTC'>UTC</option>
        <option value='Europe/Madrid'>Europe/Madrid</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
    $("#timezone-selector").on("change", function () {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('option', 'timezone', this.value || false);
        //$("form").submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So according to [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/) documentation: _"Some options affect processing of event data. Dynamically setting them will not change current event data, but will take effect for future event fetches: ...timezoneParam..."_ this shouldn't really cause FullCalendar to do anything.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I think what I'm really trying to figure out is how the [FullCalendar TimeZone example](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.9.1/demos/timezones.html) is fetching new timezone information from the server. I don't see anything that makes FullCalendar request data from the server after the on change script happens in/to the selector.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code as in the time zone example and I still can't replicate it. The only things different about my code is that I'm using ASP.NET MVC to create my json feed and for simplicity, I hard coded the selector and commented out the script that just fills the selector with options. In the demo whenever you select an option the on change seems to cause the calendar to reload and fetch new data. I'm sure f this because I can see the loading script fire when I select different options. I just need some answers or someone to talk to that know more about it than I do.